# Very weird UI-UX bug in developer story

Tags: bug, developer-story, user-experience

Yesterday I've created the developer story in my user account (seen that option in the survey).

Today I entered just to check how it looks like, and then I see some very weird bug, below the fields of

> I want to work with

where it says: javascript & php...

there are fields of

> I prefer not to work with

where it says also: javascript & php...

That does't make any sense :-O

Here is a print screen:

[image: print screen]

Comment: Please stop using inline code formatting for quotations. If you want to quote something, use quotation marks ("…"), and optionally italics. Inline code formatting is *exclusively* for things that are code or identifiers/keywords in a programming language. It is not for emphasis, or to give random things a gray background.

Comment: You hate Gray @Cody?

Comment: @CodyGray - fixed

Comment: @NikitaKurtin Thanks for providing the feedback. I can definitely see how this is confusing! We'll take a look at this as we consider other items with the Developer Story.

Answer (score 6):

It's not a bug.

Right now, you haven't put anything there, so the field is actually blank.

What you're seeing here is placeholder text (it's in a gray color), and it starts with "*e.g.*", which is an abbreviation for the Latin "*exempli gratia*"—or in English, "for example". In other words, it's just *suggesting* things that you can put there. Some developer just randomly chose these as examples.

If you hover over the area, and click on the blue "edit" button, you'll see an empty text box that has the same watermark text. If you want to put something there, then type it into that textbox. Otherwise, leave it blank and no one will see it on your public CV.

Comment: I see it is a placeholder, but as you said - I haven't put anything, so showing nothing would make a lot more sense and showing something irrelevant and confusing is: _UI - UX_ bug. Don't you agree?

Comment: @nikita yes, so you see the placeholder. That's what placeholders are for: to *hold* the *place* in the layout where content would go if provided. If you *had* put something, you'd see what you put there instead. This is an extremely common pattern and it's hard to see why you're surprised, or why you think it's a bug; it's very clearly differentiated from the places where you have entered values by different styling.

Comment: If it showed nothing, how would you know where to hover to change the values?

Comment: This placeholder is shown only to the logged user or also to external users?

Answer (score 3):

You have specified which languages you like to work with, hence they appear as tags under "I want to work with". You haven't specified any languages you don't want to work with, but instead of not showing that, it puts a placeholder that has nothing whatsoever to to with what you put down for "want to work with".

That is why it says "e.g. Javascript, php, c#...", it is just giving examples of what you might put there.